# How to run fetch statements in sequence?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Some of my code is not behaving the way I would like it too. I'm making two API requests but they are not executed in order. I read a bit and tried doing async await but couldn't reach the expected result. What am I missing here?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const selectedSdksKeys = Object.keys(selectedSdks);

    fetch(
      `/api/sdk/churn?sdk1_id=${selectedSdksKeys[0]}&sdk2_id=${selectedSdksKeys[1]}&sdk3_id=${selectedSdksKeys[2]}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setAllSdksInfo(res))

// I would like the below to happen only after the above has happened. How?

    selectedSdksKeys.forEach((id) => {
      fetch(`/api/sdk/app_count?sdk_id=${id}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            setAllSdksInfo(prev => ({...prev, res}))
    });
    });
  }, [selectedSdks]);
```

Comment: `await` before the first `fetch` should do the trick

Comment: but I can't just stick it there; throws an error. what other adjustments?

Comment: Try `useEffect(async () =>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can solve this:

1- You are missing an `await` statement, but this will require for everything that is happening in their to be wrapped into an `async` function. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

With your code, something like this should work:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const selectedSdksKeys = Object.keys(selectedSdks);

            await fetch(
                `/api/sdk/churn?sdk1_id=${selectedSdksKeys[0]}&sdk2_id=${selectedSdksKeys[1]}&sdk3_id=${selectedSdksKeys[2]}`
            )
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((res) => setAllSdksInfo(res))

            // Code that must happen after:
            await Promise.all (
                selectedSdksKeys.map((id) => {
                    return fetch(`/api/sdk/app_count?sdk_id=${id}`)
                        .then((res) => res.json())
                        .then((res) => {
                                setAllSdksInfo(prev => ({...prev, res}))
                    });
                });
            )
    })()
})
```

2- Alternatively, if you wish to skip that, you an just put the function you want to happen after the first in a `then()` statement. It should look something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const selectedSdksKeys = Object.keys(selectedSdks);

    fetch(
      `/api/sdk/churn?sdk1_id=${selectedSdksKeys[0]}&sdk2_id=${selectedSdksKeys[1]}&sdk3_id=${selectedSdksKeys[2]}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setAllSdksInfo(res))
      .then(() => {
         // Your second API call which was being run out of order:
         selectedSdksKeys.forEach((id) => {
           fetch(`/api/sdk/app_count?sdk_id=${id}`)
            .then((res) => res.json())
             .then((res) => {
                setAllSdksInfo(prev => ({...prev, res}))
          });
    });

      })
    
  }, [selectedSdks]);
```

Edit: I also noticed that you are doing a `forEach` with a fetch inside it. This will cause the fetches to be out of order. If this is a problem, consider wrapping it in a `Promise.all` with a `.map` instead of a foreach. Something like this:

```
// Your second API call which was being run out of order:
return Promise.all(selectedSdksKeys.nmap((id) => {
  return fetch(`/api/sdk/app_count?sdk_id=${id}`)
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((res) => {
        setAllSdksInfo(prev => ({...prev, res}))
     });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add another state variable to act as a flag.
You set a flag to true after first request is finished, and then check if the 1st request if finished before executing other one.

```
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const selectedSdksKeys = Object.keys(selectedSdks);
    if(!loaded){
      fetch(
        `/api/sdk/churn?sdk1_id=${selectedSdksKeys[0]}&sdk2_id=${selectedSdksKeys[1]}&sdk3_id=${selectedSdksKeys[2]}` )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
           setLoaded(true)
           setAllSdksInfo(res))
        }
     }

    if(loaded){
      selectedSdksKeys.forEach((id) => {
        fetch(`/api/sdk/app_count?sdk_id=${id}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((res) => {
            setAllSdksInfo(prev => ({...prev, res}))
       }
      });
    });
  }, [selectedSdks,loaded]);
```

Comment: And the next time `selectedSdks` changes `loaded` will still be `true`, won't it?

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions on it:

1. with `for of` loop:

   `const sequentialRequest = async () => { const list = await getPokemonList(); // [{name:string, url:string}...] for (const listItem of list.results) { const pokemon = await getPokemon(listItem.url); console.log(pokemon.name); } };`
2. with `reduce` method:

   `const sequentialRequest = async () => { const list = await getPokemonList(); // [{name:string, url:string}...] list.results.reduce(async (previousPromise, pokemon) => { await previousPromise; return (await getPokemon(pokemon.url)).name; }, Promise.resolve(undefined)); };`